# Empty variables in other script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem.

This script receive data from database, and in output element make list/text from received data.

There is OK but, when I want to use variable ID again - variable is empty. 
Why? 
How do I get a variable from the data received?

Can you help me?

```
<script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">    


  $(function testujem () 
{
//---------------------------
// 2) Send a http request with AJAX http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
//---------------------------
$.ajax({                                      
  url: 'api9.php',                  //the script to call to get data          
  data: "user=<?php echo $login_session; ?>",                        //you can insert url argumnets here to pass to api.php for example "id=5&parent=6"
  dataType: 'json',                //data format      
  success: function(data)          //on recieve of reply
  {
    var id = data[4];              //get id
    var vname = data[5];
    var vname2 = data[6];          //get name
    //--------------------------
    // 3) Update html content
    //--------------------------
    $('#output').html("<b>ID: </b>"+id+"<b> Name: </b>"+vname+"<b> Name 2: </b>"+vname2 ); 
    $('#output2').html(id);
    $('#output3').html(vname);     //Set output element html
    //recommend reading up on jquery selectors they are awesome http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/
  setInterval( testujem, 2000); // every is OK

  }  

});

});  
</script>    
<div id="output2"></div> <!-- LIST OK, var ID must exists -->    
<div id="output3"></div> <!-- LIST OK, var VNAME must exists -->    


<script>
var iddd = id; //var id is empty
var vnamee= vname; // var vname is empty I need this var in other script
.....
</script>
```

api.php

```
....
             //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 2) Query database for data
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $value = $_GET['user'];
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE tlc='$value'");            //query
  $array = mysql_fetch_row($result);                          //fetch result    

  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 3) echo result as json 
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  echo json_encode($array);

?>
```

Comment: It is - `ASYNCHRONOUS`

Comment: you are declaring `var id` in the scope of the ajax success function, so it is not visible outside of that function. You could declare id globally and then use it in the ajax function or, better, pass the id as a variable to other places you use it

Comment: Please, How do I implement it?

Answer (score 0):

The variable you've named `id` is only defined within the success function for the AJAX call. (It's a local variable to that function). Make it global and it will be available everywhere.

Also, the variable will only have a value after the AJAX call completes, so you'll want to use, e.g. a `$.Deferred` object in the code outside of the AJAX success function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how do I implement it?
Sorry, javascript I teach a few days.